# edit linux telegraf.conf with python

Tags: python, configuration, automation, telegraf

I am using `telegraf` as a measuring/monitoring tool in my tests. I need to edit `telegraf` configurations automatically; since all tests are being executed automatically.

Currently I am using `re` for configuring it; this is the process:

1. Read the whole file content.
2. Use regex to find and edit the required plugin/property.
3. Write the whole changed content to the file.

But I'm searching for a library, if exists, like [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or [`reconfigure`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reconfigure/0.1.39) to handle the configurations as an object not content.

I tried `ConfigParser.ConfigParser`, `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser` and `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser`; all return:

```
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

`reconfigure` library has specific configuration classes, each belongs to a special type of linux configs (e.g. `FSTabConfig`, `ResolvConfig` and some other types), but it doesn't contain a class for `telegraf` configs.

Does anyone have an option in mind?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried `configobj` library (as @KevinC suggested), but it loads nothing:

```
>>> import configobj
>>> c = configobj.ConfigObj('/home/zeinab/Desktop/config-modification/telegraf.conf', list_values=False)
>>> c
ConfigObj({})
```

Using `list_values=True` returns the same results.

Comment: If you want to change the configuration fot tests, then you should mock it instead of changing the file.

Comment: Dear @KlausD., I think I expressed it in a bad way. I have some applications which I want to test them; I'm not testing `telegraf`. I'm using it as a monitoring tool which is monitoring my applications' status during test. I want to use collected data for future analysis. Therefore I should have a real `telegraf`, not a mock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toml](https://pypi.org/project/toml/)

Configuration file

```
[[inputs.ping]]
  ## Hosts to send ping packets to.
  urls = ["example.org"]
  method = "exec"
```

Usage

```
import toml
conf = (toml.load("/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf"))
conf.get("inputs")
```

Output

```
{'ping': [{'urls': ['example.org'], 'method': 'exec'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [configobj](http://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but you have to specify "list_values"=False

```
c = configobj.ConfigObj('/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf', list_values=False)
```